# project layout and spring-test support issues

Tags: java, dependency-injection, junit, classpath, spring-test

We have project layout as below.

src

src/test/java

src/test/resources

and we cant add src/main/(java, resources) for code, because of earlier developemnt done.

src/test/java is having both unit and integration tests in same package as class under test has in src folder.

unit tests are running fine in current setup but issues are with running integration tests.

integration tests run perfectly fine when test class and configuration files are along side class under test, in src folder and same package as class.

but when i put test class in src/test/java and config files in src/test/resources test fails to run because of context initialization issues.

please note following about env setup

> 1 build output folder for all the src , src/test/java and src/test/resources is src folder only.
>
> 2 i am using classpath*: to specify config location, as otherwise spring fails to locate config file in resource folder.

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath*:applicationContext_getCorpAcctPrefDetailsSP.xml"})
```

> 3 tried both @Autowired and setter based DI for test classes

```
   > (i). in case of  @Autowired i get error for depedency saying  
       No unique bean of type GetCorpAccountPreferencesDetailsSP is defined expected at least 1 matching bean 
     also i am using base package scan

   > (ii). in case of Setter based DI context get initialized and unit test run but   all the dependencies injected are null in test class.
```

please expalin what can be reason for issue and any solution.

As everything is working fine when integration tests are in src folder alongside class under test.
i suspect differect source folders (src and test)creating issue when spring create context as class under test is not in same source folder as test.

thanks
nBhati

Answer (score 1):

At run-time Spring doesn't care (or know) which folder your original source code is in. All that matters is the classpath - which compiled files and which resource folders are being put on the classpath. If you are getting errors about XML files that cannot be found when you run your tests, that strongly suggests that those XML files are not on the classpath when the tests run.

Comment: hi matt, issue is with classpath only . 1>i am using eclipse to build project and its not copying resources in src/test/resources to output folder(src). any work around for this 2> if you can explain classpath*:, what difference it makes way spring looks for resources @ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath*:applicationContext_getCorpAcctPrefDetailsSP.xml"})   thanks